# Prove that $\mathcal{F}=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}\sigma(\{\{1\},..\{n\}\})$ is a field but not a $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the sigma fields on $\mathbb{N}$: $F_n=\sigma(A_n)$, where $A_n=\{\{1\},\{2\},\ldots,\{n\}\}$ for $n\ge1$. Define $\mathcal{F}:=\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}F_n$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is a field but not a $\sigma$-field.

---

For the $\sigma$ field part, I show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a countably infinite set (which is an impossibility for any $\sigma$ field). Is there any counterexample i.e., some set $A$ which belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ but not $\mathcal F$?

Comment: There is no reason for $\mathcal F$ to be closed under your "limit" operation. To prove that $\mathbb N \in \mathcal F$, you must prove that $\mathbb N \in F_n$ for at least one $n$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov i understand that the "limit" operation is poorly defined. however, I believe it is possible for $\mathbb{N}\in \mathcal{F}$ without being in any $F_n$. For example, we often write $(a,b)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty (a,b-\frac{1}{n})$. Do correct me, I'm not confident about this approach either.

Comment: It is true that $(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a, b-\frac1n)$, because every element of $(a,b)$ is an element of $(a,b-\frac1n)$ for some $n$. But, for example, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a,b-\frac1n]$ is still $(a,b)$, not $(a,b]$, because $b \notin (a,b-\frac1n]$ for all $n$. The definition of $\mathcal F$ is that it contains exactly the sets which are contained in $F_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Fortunately, $\mathbb N \in \mathcal F$, because in fact $\mathbb N \in F_n$ for every $n$...

Comment: @MishaLavrov Get it! we may consider $F_2=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}, \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N}/\{1\}, \mathbb{N}/\{2\}, \mathbb{N}/\{1,2\}\}$. I'll remove this part from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why $\mathcal F$ is not a $\sigma$-field, it helps to have a more direct understanding of what $\mathcal F$ and $\sigma(\mathcal F)$ actually are.

Since $F_n$ is generated by $\{1\}, \{2\}, \dots, \{n\}$, it can be characterized by the following property: it includes the subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and their complements. Taking the union of $F_n$ over all $n$ means that we include all finite sets (because every finite set is a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ for some $n$) and all their complements. On the other hand, if a set is infinite and its complement is infinite, then it is not in $F_n$ for any $n$, so it is not in $\mathcal F$.

In particular, $\mathcal F$ contains $\{n\}$ for every $n$, so $\sigma(\mathcal F)$ contains *every* subset of $\mathbb N$: we can obtain every subset of $\mathbb N$ as a countable union of its singleton subsets.

So to explain why $\mathcal F \ne \sigma(\mathcal F)$, we just need to find some subset of $\mathbb N$ which is neither finite nor the complement of a finite set. An example that comes to mind is $2\mathbb N$, the set of all even natural numbers.